# How to select data with sequelize from startdate upto the beginning of enddate (meaning excluding the enddate)

Tags: javascript, mysql, date, couchdb, sequelize.js

I got datasets. One of the attributes of the dataset is 'timestamp'. I want to select (efficiently) datasets that got timestamp starting from a certain start-date till a certain end-date. However the end date itself should not be included. So basically I want this: `dataSet WHERE timestamp >= startDate AND timestamp < endDate`

I've got a couchDB and I want to select with sequelize.

Let's say start- and end-date look like this:

```
var startDate = '2015-07-29 00:00:00';
var endDate = '2015-07-30 00:00:00';
```

Then everything starting from these dates should be included:

```
2015-07-29 00:00:00 (<--startDate)
2015-07-29 00:00:01
2015-07-29 00:00:02
....
2015-07-29 23:59:59 (<--my desired end-Date. It's right before endDate)
```

The enddate itself (i.e. `2015-07-30 00:00:00`) is not included.

This is what I tried:

```
db.answer.findAll({
      where: {id: { in: [myId]},
             timestamp: { between: {[startDate, endDate]}
           }
```

This gives me datasets with timestamp including start- but also end-date. I only wanted upto the end-date. Not including the end-date itself.

While the following query is what should give me the correct result (dataSet >=startDate AND dataSet < endDate)

```
  db.answer.findAll({
      where: {id: { in: [myId]},
             timestamp: { gte: startDate},
             timestamp: { lt: endDate}
           }
```

It would give me the wrong results. (Sorry I can't be specific here since I can't access the system now. I can remember though that it didn't return the result I wanted. I'll update this part when I can access the database again.)

I know I could set enddate to `2015-07-29 23:59:59`. But I'm feeling there is a more elegant approach.

Comment: Have you tried `endDate-1` in `between` ?

Comment: @vivekpansara, thanks for your answer. I'm searching for a more elegant approach. Maybe a query or an operator (e.g. "<") that would give me the desired result without manually modifying the end date. Manually modifying the end date by subtracting one seconds is a little bit hacky in my opinion. Because this date would probably not be included even though it is before the end date: 2015-07-29 23:59:59:001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second example won't work because you have the same key (timestamp) in the object twice. This is not allowed in javascript, so one of them is just ignored.

You should wrap those two in `$and`:

```
db.answer.findAll({
  where: {
    id: {in: [myId]},
    $and: [
      { timestamp: {gte: startDate} },
      { timestamp: {lt: endDate} }
    ]
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know about sequelize, but couchdb does offer a parameter `inclusive_end` that can be found in the docs: https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API

Maybe that is a starting point for a solution.